# Perl Text Balance extract bracketed returns null no error

Tags: perl

I am trying to debug a Perl Script, which uses the Text Balance extract bracketed function on some text that is enclosed in curly braces.

Unfortunately, the function returns nothing, not in the extracted or the remainder and there is error.

Is there a way where I can find out there reason for its failure? Is it possible for it to throw an exception saying for example, not able to extract because of the data structure. At the moment without knowing why, I can't really solve the problem.

Comment: Are you talking about the module [`Text::Balanced`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Balanced)? Unfortunately, what you are asking lacks enough detail to be answered specifically. Writing code is all about details, and you offer no details, not even the exact name of the module you are using. Add more information, and preferably a runnable code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Diagnostics](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Balanced#DIAGNOSTICS) section of the doc.

> In addition, on failure in any context, the `$@` variable is set. Accessing `$@->{error}` returns one of the error diagnostics listed below. Accessing `$@->{pos}` returns the offset into the original string at which the error was detected (although not necessarily where it occurred!) Printing `$@` directly produces the error message, with the offset appended. On success, the `$@` variable is guaranteed to be `undef`.

Comment: Thanks, but there is no example of how to set the error and access the error message on the function. It talks about it but gives no workable example.

Comment: Re "*there is no example of how to set the error*", huh? Cause you don't. The module does.

Comment: Re "*there is no example of how to access the error message*", huh? The text I quoted shows not one but three ways: `$@` (message with position offset), `$@->{error}` (message without position offset) and `$@->{pos}` (the position offset).